# Как получить настройку из asset

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть файл с конфигурацией с типом asset. В нем есть поле App license, в нее вставляется строка с ключом. Я хочу иметь возможность изменять ее в процессе выполнения. Однако я не нашел верного способа. Может кто пытался редактировать файлы такого типа?

Comment: Вы хотите изменить эту строку так, чтобы значение сохранилось и при следующем запуске приложения?

Comment: @M.Green нет. У меня хранится значение в бд, поэтому мне можно и без сохранения

Comment: @M.Green или пускай сохраняется. Главное чтобы можно было изменить через код

Comment: Ну, как раз в том и дело, что .asset не сохраняют изменения между запусками) потому и уточнил. А вы каким-то образом обращаетесь к этому файлу вообще? Т.е. где-нибудь используете ваше поле App license? Или именно спрашиваете каким бы образом получить ссылку на файл, чтобы обратиться к полю?)

Comment: @M.Green я сейчас работаю с библиотекой vuforia. Библиотека сама по себе обращается к полю App license. Но где это происходит я не нашел. Оно берет ключ из файла VuforiaConfiguration.asset

Comment: Сам файл этот лежит где-то внутри папки Resources вашего проекта?

Comment: @M.Green да в папке, Resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменить в режиме runtime app license key можно с помощью следующей конструкции:
void Awake () {VuforiaConfiguration.Instance.Vuforia.LicenseKey = «abcde12345 ...«; }
Но есть главное условие. Ключ должен меняться в первой сцене и до ее загрузки. Для этого собственно тут и употребляется функция Awake.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете получить любой файл из папки Resources используя стандартный статический класс Unity - [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html). А конкретно его метод [Resources.Load()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html);

В вашем случае вам потребуется примерно такая строчка кода:

```
var path = "..." //путь до файла внутри папки ресурсов, включая имя без формата 
Resources.Load<...>(path); //Здесь вместо троеточия - тип, который вы ищете
```

Comment: Для моего файла это не подходит. Однако спасибо за помощь.Я нашел решение.